# Diagram of Joomla! architecture

Tags: software-architecture

Is there some good diagram of Joomla! architecture showing main components and their most important bindings?  Something what can help newbies to quickly get architecture overview of Joomla!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link to the three [tiered architecture](http://docs.joomla.org/Archived%3aCMS_Architecture_in_1.5_and_1.6).

Here is the [component program flow](http://docs.joomla.org/Component_Program_Flow)

Just keep in mind that these are a little old. The program flow hasn't changed much, but there is some work being done on the router, so that would be something to keep your eye on.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

At the core, Joomla follows Model-View-Controller (MVC) architecture.

Image source: http://www.joomla.org/about-joomla.html

[image]

Comment: That image isn't entirely accurate. While the Controller does load the model, it injects it into the view and the view has some magic helper methods to access the model. Having said that, the diagram is how I'd prefer it to work (the controller should get the data from the model and push that into the view, not push in the model itself).